# Android: delete account if the user clears application data

Tags: android, account

I have an `Android` application that uses `Accounts` to `synchronize` data with my server. Yesterday I noticed that, if I click `Clear Data` in Settings->Apps->My App, the application data is removed **but the user account isn't**. This leads to consistency problems in my server, since suddenly the user's data is restarted without receiving a restart message.

Is there any way to delete the `Account` when the user clicks `Clear Data`? Or at least capture the event to be able to send a message to my server.

Thanks!

Comment: Nope :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700146/is-there-any-way-to-capture-the-clear-data-action-programmatically-in-applicatio

Comment: That's a shame :( I'll have to figure something out.

Comment: faced this problem..couldn't get solution...:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two ways for you to do it..

1.Not allowing the user to clear the data..this can be done by simply mentioning the..

```
android:manageSpaceActivity=".ActivityOfYourChoice"
```

in your manifest under application tag..

2.You can deleting the accounts.it can be done using the `AccountManager` and the `removeAccount` method.

First get an instance of the AccountManager:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
```

Then get a list of all accounts on the device:

```
Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
```

Comment: this. Combine it with Preferences. As when user clears the data, preferences get deleted with it. So if you can find preferences like username or something then delete the account.

Comment: @d3m0li5h3r yes..check for the preference files if they are not available delete accounts also..

Comment: Thnak you! For now I'll just use your first option, leading the user to the activity that allows him to restart the data.