# Android Detect clear data for refreshing widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-preferences

Is there any way to know in "real-time", via broadcast I guess, when a user has cleared data of the app?

I have a widget showing some user details, which are stored in the Preferences, but when the user clear the app data, I am not able to know it until the next refresh/update (the onUpdate() call) which is every 30min.

During that time, the widget is showing useless values. So I need to trigger somehow any broadcast to capture it from a receiver and update the widget when that happens.

Is that possible?

Comment: the problem is not a app, is a widget which is already in the homescreen

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is no way to get an event for that. The app's process should be terminated after clearing data. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10701338/450243

Answer (score 3):

You can use a service that implements a http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/prefs/PreferenceChangeListener.html to monitor when your preferences change.

Even if the service is killed by the system, if you use START_STICKY it will be brought to live, and you'll be able to determine if your keys are available or has been deleted. I've used this approach in a couple of apps and it works like a charm.

If you want to make even more efficient, you can add a receiver for screen on/off, so you can start your service only when the screen starts and terminate your service when the screen gets on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but is that working/being triggered when the user clear data of the app?

Comment: If the user clears the data of the app (and this last one is not stopped) yes, it's triggered. In case the system decides to stop/start your service, it's pretty straightforward detecting if your preferences contains any key inside **Service.onStart(...)**, so either way it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at this solution, you will not exactly get a callback but you will get a fighting chance to update your widget before clearing the data

```
android:manageSpaceActivity=".path.to.MyActivity"
```

This will replace the button "Clear Data" from the settings to "Manage Space". Now you can redirect the user to a custom activity that is controlled by you.

The launch of the activity will act as callback for you. Manipulate your data in your activity and use the following code

```
private void clearPreferences() {
    try {
        // clearing app data
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec("pm clear YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_GOES HERE");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
```

to clear the app data.